# Use default template parameter of one template declaration in another

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments

Let's assume I have a class template `cls1` with some default template arguments and another class template `cls2` that uses `cls1`:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2 = int, typename U = std::vector<T1>>
class cls1 {};

template<typename T1, typename T2 = int, typename U = std::vector<T1>>
class cls2 : public cls1<T1, T2, U> {};
```

Now, if I wanted to change the default of some of `cls1`'s template argument, I'd also need to *manually* change it in `cls2` for consistency.

I've already thought about using a type alias (or `constexpr` variable in the case of non-type template arguments):

```
using cls1_default_t_2 = int;
template<typename T1>
using cls1_default_u = std::vector<T1>;

template<typename T1, typename T2 = cls1_default_t_2, typename U = cls1_default_u_t<T1>>
class cls1 {};

template<typename T1, typename T2 = cls1_default_t_2, typename U = cls1_default_u_t<T1>>
class cls2 : public cls1<T1, T2, U> {};
```

Now I only need to change `cls1_default_t_2` or `cls1_default_u`.

However, this is kinda verbose depending on the number of default arguments. Additionally, if I now wanted to make another class template `cls3` use `cls2`, it'd be unfavorable to use `cls1`'s default arguments, since `cls1` is actually not directly used by `cls3`. Instead I'd again need to provide type alises (and `constexpr`s) for the default template argments of `cls2`, to use them in `cls3`:

```
// ... cls1 as seen above

using cls2_default_t_2 = cls1_default_t_2;
template<typename T1>
using cls2_default_u_t = cls1_default_u_t<T1>;

template<typename T1, typename T2 = cls2_default_t_2, typename U = cls2_default_u_t<T1>>
class cls2 : public cls1<T1, T2, U> {};

template<typename T1, typename T2 = cls2_default_t_2, typename U = cls2_default_u_t<T1>>
class cls3 : public cls2<T1, T2, U> {};
```

So, is there a more concise notation to use default template arguments of one template declaration in another?

Comment: do you need many default types? Cant you just do `using default_type = int; using default_container = std::vector<int>;` and use that?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Because then, if I had `cls3` use `default_type` and changed the default argument of `cls2`, `cls3` would not reflect this explicit change. I imagine something like `template<typename T1, typename T2 = [default of cls2's T2], typename U = [default of cls2's U]>` for `cls3` (and for `cls2` respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to avoid verbosity completely. Similar to function default arguments, you can't really get your hands on templates default arguments without some added effort. This is the best I can come up with:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2 = int, typename U = std::vector<T1>>
class cls1 {
    using value_type = T2;
    using container_type = U;
};

template<typename T1, 
         typename T2 = typename cls1<T1>::value_type, 
         typename U = typename cls1<T1>::container_type>
class cls2 : public  cls1<T1, T2, U> {};
```

Having the aliases can be beneficial not only for default parameters, so maybe this isn't really "extra" effort.

Note that `container_type` is `std::vector<int>` not a `tempalte <typename T> std::vector<T>` as you asked for. You would need to write a small helper if that is needed.

Comment: Thanks this is indeed very elegant and quite what I was looking for. Do also know a way that works with template functions/variables/aliases, though?

Comment: @Reizo make them static methods/ members / aliases of a class template